# AWS CodePipeline Docker push command returns 'no basic auth credentials'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, amazon-ecr

I am using CodePipeline to push my image to ECR, it gets the repository from the GitHub, and tries to build it before pushing it to ECR. I figured out how to login to AWS ECR by the `aws ecr get-login-password` command. But the main problem is, in the post_build stage when I am trying to run command docker push. It returns me the error that says:
**no basic auth credentials**

My buildspec.yml file:

```yaml
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 16
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Installing Dependencies
      - npm install
      - docker logout
      - aws ecr get-login-password || docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com
  build:
    commands:
      - docker build -t $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG .
      - docker tag $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Pushing the docker image
      - docker -v
      - aws --version
      - docker push $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
      - printf '[{"name":"%s","imageUrl":"%s"}]' $CONTAINER_NAME $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG > imagedefinitions.json
artifacts:
  files: imagedefinitions.json
```

Screenshot from AWS Codebuild:

[image: AWS Codebuild Error Image]

Comment: By the way, I do not get this error when I do all steps in my local environment. It gives me this errors when I am trying to do it via CodeBuild.

Comment: `aws ecr get-login-password || docker` should be `aws ecr get-login-password | docker`. You should be piping the password output from `aws ecr get-login-password` to the `docker login` command. A single `|` is a pipe. Two `||` is a boolean AND operator which just means "run this command, and if successful, run the next command".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In buildspec version 0.1, *"CodeBuild runs each command in a separate instance of the default shell in the build environment. This means that each command runs in isolation from all other commands"*. That is the reason why ecr login in pre-build phase does not effect the post-build phase

You should try to use version 0.2 which mentioned in [reference link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec.phases)

You might also try to run ecr login in the post-build phase, it may work, I guess